# Suitable solvents to dissolve Aluminum Chloride (anhydrous) without generating Hydrochloric Acid (aqueous or gas),

Tags: chemical-engineering

Hypothetically, I have a chemical tank that was brought out of service and the solid deposits at the bottom of the tank primarily contain aluminum chloride. The whole system never sees water, and the aluminum chloride is generated upstream in the process as a by-product (anhydrous under tank conditions).

It's time to clean this solid out, and water flushing seems to be an easy solution. However, previous experience tells us, extensive heat and HCl (aq) and HCl (g) generation during the flooding process, corrodes the tank material and the welded joints, inner pressure rings, etc.

I want to use an alternative solvent to dissolve the aluminum chloride without generating HCl. Ideally, I would like to clean out the tank afterward with water, to get rid of the solvent and remaining solids. My first initial screen takes me toward polar aprotic solvents with high vapor pressure.

What does this community think?

P.S. There are some other factors, such as solvent toxicity, carcinogenicity, $$ cost (tank is quite large), safe disposal of solvent at that scale, getting rid of the solvent completely from the tank, etc. might reduce the chances for some candidates.

Comment: Perhaps ask Chemistry SE

Comment: quote, "Soluble in hydrochloric acid, ethanol, chloroform and carbon tetrachloride.Slightly soluble in benzene"  .  You may not want to mess with any of those solvents.  There's unlikely to be any magic non-reactive,  non-poisonous method.

Comment: Magic method is to replace the tank by physical means only no?  All I can think of are ways to make it go kaboom...although by burning it solid fuel style, you might just end up with products that can be cleaned...